# undefined behavior in conditional operator

Tags: c++, iterator, valgrind, undefined-behavior, conditional-operator

I had to share this:

I got hung up for 2 full days on the following **trivial** error involving the Conditional Operator.

It's an easy correction, but I would like to know:

1. Why did the buggy code compile?
2. What was the bug doing?
3. Why it was so damn hard to track down?

buggy code:

```
 std::map<int, some_class>   my_map;
int key_ctr = 0;
 //...
std::map<int, some_class>::iterator it_next   =  
                                            key_ctr == 0  ?
                                 it_next  =  my_map.begin()      // BUG!!!
                                 :
                                 it_next  =  --my_map.end();     // BUG!!!!

  // .....
```

Clearly, I wrote the Conditional Operator incorrectly.  Eveyrthing works totally fine when I finally found and corrected this bug:

correct code:

```
 std::map<int, some_class>   my_map;
int key_ctr = 0;
 //...
std::map<int, some_class>::iterator it_next   =  
                                            key_ctr == 0  ?
                                 my_map.begin()              // CORRECTED!
                                 :
                                 --my_map.end();             // CORRECTED!
```

My program was just hanging when it got near the buggy part - as if it were in an infinite loop.  When I ran it with **valgrind**, I got  stuff like

```
....
==24570== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x1a7731000, 0x1c5f79000) (defined)
==24570== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x1c5f79000, 0x1e47c1000) (defined)
==24570== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x1e47c1000, 0x203009000) (defined)
==24570== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x203009000, 0x221851000) (defined)
.....
==3733== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
```

Which was totally unhelpful and pointed me in the wrong director (I thought I was allocating too much on the heap, somehow).

Again,

1. Why did the buggy code compile?
2. What was the bug doing?
3. Why it was so damn hard to track down?

Thanks kids.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. The problem is not with the ternary operator, but with using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Severe lack of parentheses diagnosed. No kidding.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas which is the uninitialized variable?

Comment: @john just edited my answer to explain that.

Comment: I love this part - "Why did the buggy code compile?". If you came up with a compiler that didn't compile buggy code, you'd be a billionaire.

Comment: haha @LuchianGrigore.  I thought that the bug was not syntacitcally correct, and so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: It is just quality of implementation, but the Right Thing would be for the compiler to complain. It clearly sees that the right hand side is using the variable uninitialized (escape analysis is trivial in this case). Then again, some compilers like gcc don't do escape analysis if no optimizations are requested.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas oh yeah, in this case it's definitely possible, but the statement sounded a lot more general :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The compiler only checks for syntax and a well-formed program. It's up to you to spot the logical bugs.

2) It's undefined behavior. And here's why:

---

```
whatever_non_POD_type it_next = condition ? it_next = whatever1 : 
                                            it_next  = whatever2;
```

Actually, you can narrow it down to:

```
It it_next = it_next = whatever;
```

it doesn't really matter what whatever is. What matters is that until the full statement executes (`;` is reached), `it_next` **is uninitialized**. That's what the

```
It it_next = ...
```

part attempts to do. **But** first, it attempts to evaluate what's on the right hand side. Which is `it_next = whatever`. Which calls `it_next.operator = (whatever)`. So **you're calling a member function on an un-initialized object**. Which is undefined behavior. Ta-da!!!

3) All undefined behavior is hard to track down. That's why you should at least be aware of common situations.

Comment: What undefined behavior? `it_next` is being assigned by both expressions in the ternary operator, and then a self assignment is being performed. I don't see the UB.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thanks for the explanation. This is really tricky. I'm not surprised the OP is feeling a bit aggrieved. It's the non-POD bit that had escaped me.

Comment: Well, gcc also complains about `int a = a = 10;`. But in this case, the situation is a lot worse since the iterator is a UDT, and not a raw pointer (which is what I was thinking it was).

Answer (score 7):

> > 3 Why it was so damn hard to track down?

Because you didn't have compiler warnings turned on?

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g    m.cc   -o m
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
m.cc:10: error: operation on ‘it_next’ may be undefined
m.cc: In function ‘void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)’:
m.cc:6: error: operation on ‘it_next’ may be undefined
make: *** [m] Error 1
```

Comment: Although, @Robᵩ, my program is fairly big and involves a large number of libraries.  Thus, `-Werror` will cause warnings from external libraries (of which I have no control) to crash compilation.  But I cannot fix these since they are in external libraries.

Comment: @Matthew Clang has a wonderful `-Wno-system-headers` command line argument that makes it generate no warnings from files in any directory specified as `-isystem /path/to/library`. I wish other compilers have something like that.